# Restore the same state in react App when redirected from iframe

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-context

I am working in react.js. I have embedded an iframe in one of the component which is in other domain. And the button inside the iframe redirect to same react app.

But on redirecting it clears all of the state and I loose my state before redirection. Is there a way to restore all the state when redirected from iframe.

```
import React from 'react'

function iframe() {
    return (
        <div>
            <iframe
                title="grafana"
                className="detailIframe"
                src={`http://ipaddress/alllist`}
            ></iframe>
        </div>
    )
}
export default iframe
```

iframe has a button that redirects to detail page in react app on click.

```
onClick="window.top.location.href = 'http://ipaddress/detailpage'">
```

How can I use same state when redirected to detail page?

Comment: If I understand correctly, you need some kind of persistence between both domains and restore the state from the persistence when the redirection happens.